# Why are Markov Chains used in gerrymandering?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, markov-chains

I'm wondering why Markov chains are used in gerrymandering. I would like to do a little mathematical investigation on this topic, but I don't understand whats the use of Markov Chains in gerrymandering.

Thank you

Comment: What's your starting point here? Where did you read or hear that Markov chains are used in gerrymandering? (Also, do you know the basic concepts of what a Markov chain is? If not, then you should probably start there instead.)

Comment: Do you mean "to analyze gerrymandering"?

Comment: I wish we had more politicians who know about Markov chains (I would settle for elementary probability and statistics).

Comment: Yes, I mean the mathematics behind the analysis of gerrymandering.

Comment: This is a rather broad question.  Could you provide details about what you know and what type of answer you’re looking for?